# Could we use this sentence without using "respectively"?

Tags: grammar

> Two tangents are drawn through points A and B

or

> Two tangents are drawn through points A and B, respectively.

or

> A tangent is drawn through point A and point B.

Which among these is correct to use?

Comment: From context ("Two points" connoting "Two *different* points") each line must be distinct from the other one, ergo 'respectively' is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Two tangents are drawn through each of points A and B.

Comment: If you were dealing with arbitrary points from a finite set of points located on the same circle, and you were to pick two of those points with replacement at random to assign each a tangent line, then there is a real possibility that the two tangent "lines" could in fact be the same line; as such, your task would be to draw tangent[s] through A and B respectively (not necessarily exclusive from the other, but each assigned with respect to the task).  But if the points were instead chosen without replacement (precluding possibility of duplicate), then this would not be possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot @11qq00

Comment: Thanks a lot @EdwinAshworth

Comment: Lol, this question could use a diagram. My understanding is that by definition, a tangent can contact only one point on a circle ([rules are different for complex curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Multiple_tangents_at_a_point)), which precludes the idea that any one tangent is drawn through both A and B. It remains to clarify intent: should there be two tangents *per* point, or total? At any rate, "respectively" would be misapplied in this example and would only confuse.

Comment: @AndyBonner There could be a common tangent to two circles, though, and A and B could be the points where the tangent touches both circles. Think of a railway line touching two or more locomotive wheels.

Comment: In the technical literature, "respectively" links two lists of equal length: "Tangents C and D are drawn at points A and B, respectively." means that tangent C passes through point A and tangent D passes through point B. None of your examples involves this case, and none needs "respectively."

Comment: *One tangent is drawn through point A and another through point B.*

Comment: @Chemomechanics I vote you turn yours into an answer, because that's the real *POINT* here, the usage of "respectively." The rest of us just got off onto a *TANGENT*. :-)

Comment: Are the points on the circle?  More than one unique tangent line (in fact, I believe exactly two) passes through each point outside of the circle.  Context could help clarify whether any of the three sentences above are ambiguous.